# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer un arreglo en java?

Tags: java, array

tengo un problema con este código, el problema es que cuando se ejecutan estas líneas de código:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++ ){
                
                System.out.println("Ingresar calificacion:  ");
                 calif[i] = ca.nextInt();
                
            }
```

En lugar de ejecutarse tres veces como esta declarado, se ejecuta seis veces, por lo que causa problemas en mi otra función.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Este es mi código completo:

```
package calificaciones;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Ingresar {
        
    int calif[]= new int[3];
        public void ingresar_c()
        {
    
             Scanner ca= new Scanner(System.in);
               
            
for(int i=0; i<3; i++ ){                
System.out.println("Ingresar calificacion:  ");
calif[i] = ca.nextInt();
}
            
}           
    public void promedio()
{
    
Ingresar p = new Ingresar();   
            
p.ingresar_c();
            
int suma = 0;
                       
for(int a=0; a<3; a++)
{
                
suma = (suma + calif[a])/3;
}            
System.out.println("Tu promedio es de: " + suma);    
}        
}
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no es necesario instanciar la clase si haces el método estático.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas probable es que en el método main que tengas,para hacer uso de los métodos ingresar_c y promedio estés creando un nuevo objeto de la clase `Ingresar`...

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Ingresar r=new Ingresar();
    
    r.ingresar_c();
    r.promedio();
}
```

pero en tu método promedio al tener un objeto ya creado de la clase `Ingresar` y ademas hacer uso del método `ingresar_c` estas duplicando la solicitud de datos es por ello que te pide 6, no es necesario que el método promedio tenga un objeto creado ni que invoques el método `ingresar_c` dentro de ella si vas a crear un objeto de tu clase `Ingresar` en el main y hacer uso de sus métodos,recuerda que tu array `calif` es propio de esa clase ;)

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Ingresar { 
    
    int calif[]= new int[3];
    
    public void ingresar_c(){
    Scanner ca= new Scanner(System.in);   
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++ ){                
    System.out.println("Ingresar calificacion:  ");
    calif[i] = ca.nextInt();
         }
     }           
    public void promedio(){
        
    double suma = 0;
    //usa double para promedios                        
    for(int a=0; a<3; a++){           
    suma = suma + calif[a];
    }            
    System.out.println("Tu promedio es de: " +Math.round(suma/3*100)/100.0);
//redondea a 2 decimales    
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Ingresar r=new Ingresar();
    
    r.ingresar_c();
    r.promedio();
    
    }
    }
```